# PHP spl_autoload_register() doesn't open a file with namespace

Tags: php

Guys I'm facing a problem by using `spl_autoload_register` function. What I'm using is `XAMPP` in its `htdocs` directory there is another directory called `boot`. This directory has 2 files a `Car class` file and just a `Main` php file. That class using `namespace` `boot`. I want to load that class by using this function `spl_autoload_register` but error is coming like this. What I'm doing wrong.

`Warning: require(boot\Car.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\Main.php`

Code Car.php

```
<?php
namespace boot;

class Car
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Constructor has been created!';
    }
}
```

Code Main.php

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($className){
    require $className  . '.php';
});

use boot\Car;
$car = new Car;
```

Comment: can you confirm `C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\Main.php` is the exact path ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam yes

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam your duplicate marked question doesn't solve my issue

Comment: Have you checked all the cases in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2975952

Comment: Just use `require 'path'` and check that file is accessible, if that works then the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I try to add this statement in `Main.php` and it's work fine  `require 'Car.php';` no errors are coming.

Comment: Rather than giving relative paths use absolute paths like `C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\Car.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154349/discussion-between-ven-nilson-and-thamaraiselvam).

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\Car.php'; also executed without no error.

Comment: problem is in path, the file required is actually this one: `C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\boot\Car.php`

Comment: @Kazz can you elaborate this

Comment: when you call `require` with relative path that is the same as `__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path` and `__DIR__` contains full path to the directory of php file where you use it, that means if you want to use this function you have to keep directory stucture same as namespaces because variable `$className` contains namespace as well, quick solution for you is remove `boot` from `$className` that will change project root as base for `boot` namespace...

Comment: @VenNilson Basically what problem you facing is, Your class `Car` is not in `boot` directory.
When you use statement like this `use boot\Car` then `require` statement will understood this path as an autoload path i.e `boot\boot\Car.php`.

In that path second `boot\` is just a fictitious namespace name. So remove it.

Code:

spl_autoload_register(function ($className){
    require str_replace('boot\\',"",$className) . '.php';
});

Comment: @Kazz Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Few examples:

Directory structure:

```
project folder
- Main.php
- Car.php
- Test.php
- Foo
- - Bar.php
- - Baz
- - - Qux.php
```

Test.php

```
class Test {}
```

Foo\Bar.php

```
namespace boot\Foo;
class Bar {}
```

Foo\Baz\Qux.php

```
namespace Foo\Baz;
class Qux {}
```

Main.php

```
//__DIR__ === C:\xampp\htdocs\boot    

spl_autoload_register(function ($className){
    //__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
    require_once preg_replace('/^[\\\\\/]?boot[\\\\\/]?/', '', $className). '.php';
});

// both require same file but namespace must be same as defined in file
$t = new boot\Car; // work
$t = new Car; // do not work because in Car.php is namespace `boot`
// required file: C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\Car.php

// both require same file but namespace must be same as defined in file
$t = new boot\Test; // do not work because in Test.php is no namespace 
$t = new Test; //work
// required file: C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\Test.php

// both require same file but namespace must be same as defined in file
$t = new boot\Foo\Bar; // work
$t = new Foo\Bar; // do not work because in Bar.php is namespace `boot\Foo`
// required file: C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\Foo\Bar.php

// both require same file but namespace must be same as defined in file
$t = new boot\Foo\Baz\Qux; // do not work because in Qux.php is namespace `Foo\Baz`
$t = new Foo\Baz\Qux; // work
// required file: C:\xampp\htdocs\boot\Foo\Baz\Qux.php
```